# Prove the solution of an exponential equation is in a certain interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, exponential-function

$$\frac{(e^x-2)}{x-1}+\frac{(e^x-1/4)}{x+1}=0$$

The above equation are given, and the question asks to show the equation has a solution in interval $(-1,1)$.

I have no idea at all. I have just studied continuous function and I think it might be done by using intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x \to 1$ the function on LHS tends to $-\infty$ and $x \to -1$ it tends to $\infty$. Being a continuous function it takes all real values in the interval $(-1,1)$.

Remember that $2 <e <4$.

Comment: Is it possible to write more standard process? I mean, I can write the function f(x)=0 is in the interval [limf(1),limf(-1)], thus there exists a number c (-1,1), such that f(c)=0, by ivt? Does it work?

Comment: @ChangHenry IVP is exactly what I am using. All you need is the fact that $f$ takes both positive and negative values and I am saying that if $x$ is close to $1$ then $f(x)$ is negative and if $x$ is close to $-1$ the $f(x)$ is positive.